# How can I add a class to the active menu item using bootstrap scrollspy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm using this code, but it doesn't work as I am expecting.

```
$("#myNavbar").on("activate.bs.scrollspy", function(){
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('hvr-overline-reveal');
    var currentItem = $(".nav li.active > a");
    currentItem.parent("li").addClass("hvr-pulse");
    currentItem.addClass("hvr-overline-reveal");
}) 
});
```

The main issue is this:

```
$("#myNavbar").on("activate.bs.scrollspy", function(){
}
```

It activates jQuery when you scroll the page. How can I add a class to the `li` element when it occurs?

https://jsfiddle.net/Hnk9W/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example' });
```

Replace navbar example with your navbar
Read the Documentation : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: @Justas which help you want me about this class??

Comment: i want to add class when scrollspy event fires up... just want add second class ON HOVER event

Comment: if this answer helps accept it as an answer and post a new question with details of your news class etc.

Comment: you didnt answered to my question

Comment: i push buttom accept because for your patience... your answer is wrong